# Rhomobile MapView.create map_params, Windows7

Tags: geocoding, rhomobile

i am trying to do geo-mapping using rhostudio in windows7. But each time i want to show on map(MapView.create map_params), the screen freezes. Please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to sort out the problem, the issues was i was using rhosimulator to render. Just found out that for mapping you need to use either simulator or device but not rhosimulator.